# React Ant Design - best place to generate columns in functionnal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My app have a very intensive table usage. I generate quite complex tables, and filters are calculated automatically (map on array of values to get possible values in the current dataset for example). So basically my point is that it can be intensive on some pages.

What would be the best place to generate columns in a React App with Antdesign, performance wise? Note that we mostly use functionnal components, with useState hook when needed.

- in a useState hook, and display the table once the generation fulfilled
- directly in the `<Table columns={generateCols()}>`
- something else?

IMO the good point of the first is that if the component re-render, it will not re-generate the columns, but I'm not sure about that. The second is simpler to maintain and less complex, but if a re-render implies generating again the columns, I'm not sure about the gain!

Thanks

Example of code with columns stored in useState (may be some typos, but you get the overall picture):

```js
export function TableComponent(props: Props) {
  const { meal, similarMeals } = props;

  const [tableCols, setTableCols] = useState<ColumnProps<meal>[] | undefined>(
    undefined
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setTableCols(
      generateSimilarMealColumns(
        meal.countOfIngredients,
        meal.similarMeals
      )
    );
  }, [meal.countOfIngredients, meal.similarMeals]);

  return (
    <>
      <Container className={styles.section}>
        {tableCols !== undefined ? (
          <Table<meal>
            rowKey="_id"
            columns={tableCols}
            dataSource={similarMeals}
            pagination={false}
            expandRowByClick={true}
            expandedRowRender={(record) => <p>{record.longDescription}</p>}
          />
        ) : (
          <Spin />
        )}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you currently experiencing perf problems?

Comment: Basically, it is not a problem yet. But things are starting to stack up, and by the number of tables we have to display in the whole app, I would just like to get the better way as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me preface by saying don't prematurely do perf stuff. If it works, keep going until it doesn't.

Secondly, one thing that stands out to me is that **you are calling a function to generate the columns every time your Table component is rendered**. If the component rendering your `Table` component gets re-rendered, then you might be doing a bunch of extra work for no reason.

Show the rest of the component that renders your `Table` component - this might be a good use case for [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

EDIT: As a possibility, you might be able to fix the whole thing simply by doing this:

```js
<Table columns={useMemo(generateCols,[... list of dependencies that are used in here])}>
```

Comment: `useMemo` would be my goto here. Similarly, `reselect`, although redux oriented, can do nice stuff memoizing state.

Comment: thanks for answer! I just added an example on my first post. I had to change variable names and everything because it's very business centric in my case. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tmos - The code you've posted in your edited answer leaves no obvious room for optimization, unlike your first example. You are doing it right - only regenerating the tables cols when things change. But be careful - similarMeals sounds like an array - so it might be referentially always different on re-renders, while it's contents is actually identical. Again, though, don't do perf work if there are no perf problems.

Comment: thanks @Adam, indeed, I was doing somes tables like description (calling the function in render), and some like my example (storing it in the state). until now I haven't seen any difference, but I was looking to know the better way between both. 

Thanks a lot for the informations!